# Should the Roaming directory for MikTex be removed?

Tags: miktex

I am on a Windows system using `MikTeX` and `TexStudio` as my editor.

The other day while doing some styling on my `scrreprt` class it was suggested that I use the new functions from the new `KOMA-script v3.16` rather than what I was using. So I tried the new commands and they weren't recognised, I checked on the `MikTeX` `Package Manager` and saw that the version of the `KOMA-script` package was `v3.16`, however the log file still reported `v3.12` for my `scrreprt.cls`.

After uninstalls re-installs of packages and such I looked for the actual files on the system and found that in the `C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex` there was a `koma-script` folder with the `v3.12` files while in the `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex` were the new ones. I deleted the files in the `Roaming` and suddenly the commands worked and the log file said I was using `v3.16`.

So that prompts me to ask, as I haven't heard anything about it, should I delete the files in the `Roaming` folder so that the editor uses the latest self updating ones or not? Like is there some other functionality?

Comment: You have a multiuser installation and the files in the roaming directory were installed by the user (probably on-the-fly) and so must be updated by the user. User packages always take precendence. Run the update manager in user mode to update them. You can deinstall such user packages with the user package manager, then the admin packages are seen again.

Comment: Ah I see so it may be that another editor automatically installed them with the user installation as it has access to requesting packages. Could that explain how it happened?

Comment: No, probably MiKTeX itself installed it on the fly. You can change that behaviour in its settings.

Comment: Perhaps it makes me a bad man, but I often delete an outdated .sty file in order to force MikTeX to auto-update.  In my defense, no one else uses my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a multiuser installation and the files in the roaming directory were installed by the user (probably on-the-fly) and so must be updated by the user. User packages always take precendence. Run the update manager in user mode to update them. You can deinstall such user packages with the user package manager, then the admin packages are seen again.

Comment: How can we make sure MikTeX is called in admin mode, when running on the fly to prevent user mode? I have the same issue and worried that even if I uninstall the user packages, they can be installed in the future.